# Mutliple requests causes long delays/locks

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have an issue that when I call an endpoint multiple times before a requests resolves the request response time blows out massively.

Some example code.

In the controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    //[Authorise("Bearer")]
    [Route("test")]
    public string GetDashboardTest()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        Logger.Information("GetDashboardDataAsync", "Starting API at {0:hh:mm:ss.fff}", now);
        var result = = "Hello World";
        var done = DateTime.Now;
        var time = decimal.Truncate((done.Ticks - now.Ticks) / 10000);
        Logger.InformationAsync("GetDashboardDataAsync", "Ending API at {0:hh:mm:ss.fff}, duration {1}", done, time);
        return result;
    }
```

This runs super fast. Around 20 ms round trip

When I add auth in it we get this issue around this snippet of code.

```
    public async Task<Response<bool>> UserRequiresReAuthAsync(string username)
    {
        var response = new Response<bool>();
        // This seems to cause locking when i add logging either side of it.
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

        // If i use this instead its alot faster but still causes locking
        //var user = await _identityUserRepo.GetAsync(a => a.NormalizedUserName == username.ToUpper());

        response.Succeeded = true;
        response.Data = user == null || user.ReAuth;

        return response;
    }
```

Where get async is.

```
    returnedColumnsExpression = returnedColumnsExpression ?? (model => model);

    entitySet
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(where)
        .Select(returnedColumnsExpression)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
```

When I added this and spam the endpoint the request total time balloons out to 10 seconds each.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to avoid it.

Im running dotnetcore 1.1.1

I have tried makeing calls nonasync and adding no tracking.

Comment: Just as a test: Try adding ConfigureAwait(false) to your queries. Theoretically you don't need this anymore on dotnet core.. but worth the test.